# How to pass inserting old values to mysql? It inserts the old lines too

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a txt file it is updating the values every 5 minutes like rss.
I recording the values with curl and it is automaticly inserting to the Mysql.

But there is a problem. In txt file when I record the new lines it is inserting them with old lines.

Php lines to insert.

```
$addvalue = "INSERT INTO city SET cities='$cities', date='$date'";
mysql_query($addvalue)
```

Mysql lines

```
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (1, 'ISTANBUL', '2013-06-19 18:09:39');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (2, 'IZMIR', '2013-06-19 15:06:35');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (3, 'LONDON', '2013-06-19 11:17:15');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (4, 'BERLIN', '2013-06-18 06:12:21');
```

with new lines it saves old ones again

```
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (1, 'ISTANBUL', '2013-06-19 18:09:39');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (2, 'IZMIR', '2013-06-19 15:06:35');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (3, 'LONDON', '2013-06-19 11:17:15');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (4, 'BERLIN', '2013-06-18 06:12:21');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (1, 'ISTANBUL', '2013-06-19 18:09:39');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (2, 'IZMIR', '2013-06-19 15:06:35');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (3, 'LONDON', '2013-06-19 11:17:15');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (4, 'BERLIN', '2013-06-18 06:12:21');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (5, 'MOSCOW', '2013-06-20 19:15:33');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (6, 'PARIS', '2013-06-20 12:18:32');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (7, 'NEW YORK', '2013-06-20 21:17:25');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (8, 'OSLO', '2013-06-20 07:17:44');
```

and I try to saved them like that

```
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (1, 'ISTANBUL', '2013-06-19 18:09:39');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (2, 'IZMIR', '2013-06-19 15:06:35');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (3, 'LONDON', '2013-06-19 11:17:15');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (4, 'BERLIN', '2013-06-18 06:12:21');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (5, 'MOSCOW', '2013-06-20 19:15:33');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (6, 'PARIS', '2013-06-20 12:18:32');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (7, 'NEW YORK', '2013-06-20 21:17:25');
INSERT INTO `city` VALUES (8, 'OSLO', '2013-06-20 07:17:44');
```

I dont want to save the same old lines in txt. when the new lines come it should add to mysql bottom of old ones.. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: for what i've understand u should use UPDATE statement

Comment: Mark that column as UNIQUE in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put city name as unique index when you want to insert the value it will show error. So you will avoid duplicate entries.

**From [manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)**

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the REPLACE statement instead of INSERT :

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Answer (score 1):

make cities unique, and check "on duplicate key update" statement of mysql.